# Encendido de led en ensamblador con ATMEGA328P

Tags: ensamblador

Tengo que hacer un programa en ensamblador que haga uso de un led y un botón con el microcontrolador ATMEGA328P, en este caso configuré la salida (led) en el pin 1 del puerto B, y la entrada (botón) en el pin 5 del mismo puerto:

```
.include "m328pdef.inc"     //cabecera para el ATMEGA328P
.def tmp = R16              //registro temporal R16
.def boton = R17            //registro del boton R17
.def led = R18              //registro del led R18
.def puertoB = R19          //registro del puertoB R19
.org 0x0000                 //inicio del programa
    rjmp CONFIGURACION      //salto a la configuracion de I/O

CONFIGURACION:
    ldi led, 0b00000010     //se carga el valor 1 en binario al registro del led, el valor del pin 5 queda en 0 porque es entrada
    out DDRB, led           //cargamos este valor al puerto B (DDRB)
    ldi boton, 0b00100000   //activamos el pull-up al boton de entrada
    out PORTB, boton        //cargamos el valor al puerto B
```

Hasta aquí llevamos solo la configuración de entradas/salidas, el programa debe de togglear el estado del led, si el led está apagado el botón debe encenderlo y permanecer ese estado, si se vuelve a pulsar el botón, el led debe apagarse y permanecer así hasta que de nuevo se pulse el botón.

Entonces en una "función" llamada "inicio" he logrado extraer el valor del botón y almacenarlo en una variable temporal "tmp":

```
INICIO:
    in puertoB, PINB        //se lee el puerto B y se guarda su valor en "puertoB"
    and puertoB, boton      //se extrae el dato del pin que nos interesa (el botón)
    mov tmp, puertoB        //se guarda el valor en la variable temporal (tmp)
```

Pero a partir de aquí ya no sé cómo hacer que el led se comporte como debe comportarse con el valor obtenido de la entrada. ¿Alguna idea?